# Python factory class with dynamic imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, factory-method, dynamic-loading

I'm trying to write a factory class that essentially provides a user-friendly frontend to creating objects of different kinds depending on keywords. So the user will just have to import this module, and then use `module.factory.make_new` with the relevant keywords.

The directory structure will be pretty flat: this file will sit in a directory along with `SubclassA.py` which defines the class `SubclassA` likewise for `SubclassB` etc. That is, each subclass is in its own module of the same name.

If the user wants to dig a bit deeper, they can provide their extension to the code by writing `SubclassC.py` which provides class `SubclassC` and then add the line `factory.register_format("subclassc", "SubclassC")` to the bottom of this file (or, eventually, this will be handled by a config file). Here's what I have so far:

```
import importlib


class TrackerFactory:
    def __init__(self):
        self.subclass_dict = {}

    def register_format(self, subclass_name, subclass_package):
        fmt = importlib.import_module(subclass_package)
        self.subclass_dict[subclass_name] = getattr(fmt, subclass_package)

    def make_new(self, subclass, **kwargs):
        return self.subclass_dict[subclass](subclass, **kwargs)


factory = TrackerFactory()
factory.register_format("subclassA", "SubclassA")
factory.register_format("subclassB", "SubclassB")
```

I'm just wondering what the possible downsides of this sort of approach are, and what kind of gotchas I might have to look out for. Is there a better way to do this? I get the feeling I can achieve what I want with class methods and a class variable dictionary, and thus avoid hardcoding an instance of the factory, but I couldn't get it to work...

Some things I'm not bothered by:

- sneaky hidden imports not at the top of the file (the advantages of dynamically loading the dependencies of only the registered formats outweigh the poor style, for me). And in any case, this is only used to load a very specific type to module. The modules themselves being loaded in this way (`SubclassA` etc) could have lots of unusual dependencies.

Some things I've already thought of:

- extend the `register_format` method to allow the module name and class name to differ
- use some `try`/`except` logic
- since, in my use case, there will actually be only one or a few objects actually instantiated, I could juggle things around so that the import is actually in `make_new` (and `subclass_dict` just holds a string rather than the function), and then registering a format you won't use that you don't have the dependencies for wouldn't choke.

Comment: (1) What project directory structure does this code expect? (2) The `import_module()` function takes a module name as its first argument, but you are calling it `subtype_name`. Why are you describing a module as though it were a type? (3) All of which makes me think I don't understand your purpose, and I suspect others could be in the same boat. Perhaps you can edit your question to explain both how to set up an intended use case (directory structure and file names) and what the benefits are.

Comment: Thanks for those comments. "type" was just an unfortunate word choice. The directory structure is pretty flat and is explained in the second para now. I am currently relying on the fact that the modules I'm importing this way all contain a class of the same name as the module name, which is maybe a confusing way to do things...

Comment: It sounds a bit like you are trying to make a plug-in system.

Comment: Yeah. Or rather, I'm writing this in such a way that it could easily support plugins.

Comment: "I also want to allow the user to provide their extension by making `SubclassC.py` which provides class `SubclassC`. then add the line `factory.register_format("subclassc", "SubclassC")` to the bottom of this file." Are you users editing the file? To double check,  users will be editing _your library's code_? If not can you add the feature to your code. Afterwards I think I could give you a helpful review.

Comment: From your description it really sounds like your edit represents an answer-invalidation. CRSE is not forum-like; we seek to represent questions as moments in time for which a given answer is generally applicable, and updates that remove that generality are discouraged.

Comment: As such, I don't think you have many other options than to roll back your most recent edit, and carry it to a new question (with more detail)

Comment: @Reinderien I can see where you're coming from, but I think the original question just wasn't very interesting (and your answer is clearly the right response) so it's not clear to me it's worth preserving the original one. But I don't know what other people think?

Comment: @Peilonrayz It's more that I'd like to write things so that this functionality would be easy to add on, rather than that I want to now create a system for plugins right now.

Comment: @Seamus One way to look at it is that by changing the question so that it invalidates Reinderien answer, you have wasted the time and effort he put in to answering the original question.  The answer might be upvoted in the context of the original question, but not in that of the revised question.  The polite thing to do is to restore the original question and then ask a new revised question. Link to this question from the new one.

Comment: In the revised question, clarify (1) in "The user will need to import the module", which module is "the module" (TrackerFactory.py or SubclassA.py)? and (2) in "then add the line factory.register_format("subclassc", "SubclassC") to the bottom of this file", which file is "this file" (TrackerFactory.py or SubclassC.py)?

Comment: OK I rolled back the edits. Apologies to Peilonrayz who did some extensive editing on the language of the question. Given the other comments here, I'm going to think a bit more about the code before asking again

Answer (score 1):

If a factory pattern is indeed called for - much of the time it is not - there is an easier way that needs neither `importlib` nor explicit registration calls.

If you follow something like this layout:

```
mypackage/
mypackage/__init__.py
mypackage/tracker_factory.py
mypackage/trackers/__init__.py
mypackage/trackers/type_a.py
mypackage/trackers/type_b.py
...
```

then in `mypackage/trackers/__init__.py`:

```
from .type_a import TypeA
from .type_b import TypeB
...
```

then your factory can `import mypackage.trackers as all_trackers`, do a `dir(all_trackers)`, and every subtype that you care about will be listed. Instead of a dynamic import plus runtime registration calls, this uses traditional imports and will look up the individual type using `getattr()` on the module object. The class and module names are automatically able to differ though it would not be a good idea to do so. The subtype modules would still be able to import, as you put it, "unusual dependencies".

If you are concerned about the performance impact of initializing modules that you may not end up using, I think this concern is unwarranted - though of course you haven't shown any code as evidence one way or the other. A properly-written Python module should be fast and safe to load, and should only incur execution expenses when something is called.

Comment: Reading through what I wrote, I realise that what I have above doesn't do one of the things I originally wanted to do, which is have different keywords effectively call the same subclass with different options. That's why your approach isn't ideal. I guess I could make each user keyword into a class that is just a subclass with some parameters fixed...

Comment: This approach will not impede the passage of `kwargs` from your factory method to the constructor.

Comment: How does this accommodate a user adding their own `type_c.py`? Would they also need to edit the `__init__.py` to add a `from .type_c import TypeC`?  Perhaps `__init__.py` could loop over the files in the directory and use `importlib.import_module()`?

Comment: In thinking about your answer, I realised that my code isn't working as intended. I've edited my question to make clear that this sort of solution isn't suitable: 1, it doesn't give me an abstraction of user-friendly keywords for object creation, and 2, all dependencies of all modules need to be satisfied for this code to work.